# Exporting database connections from MySQL Workbench into HeidiSql

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench, heidisql

Has anyone successfully exported their db connections from MySQL Workbench into HeidiSql?

Workbench's export gives me XML files (tools>config>backup connections) but apparently HeidiSql expects a .txt file to import.

Are the two just simply not compatible?

I have a large number of connections to various DBs and I'm not looking forward to having to manually set them all up in HeidiSql :(

Comment: Even I am looking for the same answer.

Comment: Sadly I never found a way to do it.  I just decided to stay with Workbench.